# JavaFX : How to dynamically add textfields and buttons on user input

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm a bit new to Java and I'm trying to make an User Interface in JavaFX that dynamically adds a TextField and an "edit" Button next to it whenever the user presses a "+" button.
I understand that it is a good idea to try and store these buttons and text fields in a list, but I'm not sure how to have them put on the interface

```java
ListView<Button> dinamicButtons = new ListView<Button>();
ListView<TextField> dinamicTextFields = new ListView<TextField>();
int quantityOfDinamicFieldsAdded =0;
 Button add= new Button ("+");
        add.setOnAction(e -> {
            dinamicButtons .add(quantityOfDinamicFieldsAdded , new Button("Edit"));
            dinamicTextFields .add(quantityOfDinamicFieldsAdded , new TextField("nome do Componente"));
            quantityOfDinamicFieldsAdded ++;
            //remove dynamically added buttons and text fields
            for (int i=0 ; i<quantityOfDinamicFieldsAdded ; i++){
                //add them all back
            }
        });
```

Comment: You probably mean "dynamic"

Comment: Using `ListView<Button>` and `ListView<TextField>` are bad ideas. You should have something like `ListView<POJO>` or `ListView<String>`. Then use the `CellFactory` to create the Button and TextField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo that adds a `Button` and `TextField` to `ListView`. The [POJO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) I created named `CellData` just keeps track of the `TextField`’s prompt text and the `Button`’s text. The key to this is using a `CellFactory`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ListView<CellData> listView = new ListView();
        listView.setCellFactory((ListView<CellData> param) -> {
            ListCell<CellData> cell = new ListCell<CellData>() {
                TextField textField = new TextField();
                Button button = new Button();
                HBox hBox = new HBox(textField, button);
                {
                    HBox.setHgrow(textField, Priority.ALWAYS);
                }

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(CellData item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null) {
                        textField.setPromptText(item.getTextFieldPromptText());
                        button.setText(item.getButtonText());
                        button.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> {
                            System.out.println("You clicked " + button.getText() + ". TextField Prompt text is " + textField.getPromptText() + ".");
                        });

                        setGraphic(hBox);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        });        

        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(1);        
        Button button = new Button("Add Item");
        button.setOnAction((event) -> {
            listView.getItems().add(new CellData("Prompt Text: " + i.get(), "Button: " + i.getAndIncrement()));
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(button, listView);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }    
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is of great help, Thanks! But I can't seem to use this CellFactory (it says CellData cannot be resolved to a type even though all imports are OK) - without this I cannot tell apart which button corresponds to each TextField, or which textField is which, etc? I managed to make the UI as I wanted (pretty similar to yours) but I didn't use CellFactory or a POJO list. Don't know how I can make it so I can differentiate them from each other (or how to get the fields' textes)

Comment: This is proof of concept. You should be able to tailor these ideas to fit your situation.

Comment: `CellData` is a POJO that I create for this example. You need to create an object that works with your `ListView`'s data/situation.

Comment: Basically When you look at `ListView<CellData> listView = new ListView()`, your situation should be similar. `ListView<YourPOJO> listView = new ListView()`. Then replace every instance of `CellData` with `YourPOJO`.

Comment: unrelated: don't create nodes in updateItem, ever ;)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it with your help, I'm pretty new to java, I didn't even know what a POJO was, I thought it and CellData were some kind of imported class...

Comment: @MartinStrotbek Sorry I assumed you knew what a POJO was.

Comment: @Sedrick no need to apologize, i'm thanking you for having me learn these concepts

Comment: @Basil Bourque, Nice catch and fix!