# Left Justify Buttons Inside of an HBox (inside a pagnition if that matters)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Been learning JavaFX in my freetime, and thought a simple schedule application would be a good practice. My current goal is output all members of an ArrayList, and have buttons for each, allowing to mark task as completed, or edit a task. However I'm struggling with button placement, I have an HBox containing a label and two buttons, I can get them spaced, but since the task are different sized strings, I cant get the buttons to line up with each other. Is there any way to have them base their position on the left side, and not on the right after the string?

Here is my current code:

```
@FXML
public Node createPage(int pageIndex){
    ListView<Event> eventView = new ListView<>();
    int fromIndex = pageIndex * maxPerPage;
    int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + maxPerPage, schedule.size());
    List<Event> eventString = schedule.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    //testing buttons
    eventView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Event>(){
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Event item, boolean empty){
            super.updateItem(item,empty);
            if(empty || item == null){
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else{
                Label label = new Label(item.display());

                Button editButton = new Button ("Edit");

                Button completedButton = new Button ("Completed");

                editButton.setOnAction(event ->{
                    System.out.println("done");
                });

                completedButton.setOnAction(event ->{
                    System.out.println("done");
                });

                HBox eventHbox = new HBox(label);

                HBox buttonHbox = new HBox(editButton,completedButton);

                buttonHbox.setSpacing(50);

                buttonHbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

                HBox.setMargin(buttonHbox,new Insets(0,0,0,200));

                HBox hbox = new HBox(eventHbox,buttonHbox);

                setGraphic(hbox);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

also eventually I will need to figure out how to send the element the button is aligned with into the function for when the button is pressed if anyone has tips for that

I have tried using `BASELINE_RIGHT` instead of `CENTER_RIGHT` and if I change the passing in `setMargin()` anymore or to like max or something it'll make me scroll over to see it

EDIT::
trying to figure out TableView but not getting it, for person who wanted photos, (the want to have is created with data that is all same size, ideally button placemen does not depend on data length)

here is what I currently have:[image: currently have]

and here is what I want to have [image: want to have]

Comment: Use a [TableView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html), not a ListView.  Remember to add TableColumns to your TableView.

Comment: Thank You!!. Like I said just now learning so honestly alot of this is from chatgpt. Slowly learning the shit myself and can kinda make their code more practical.

Comment: Did you want each row of your `ListView` to be composed of three elements across: text, button, button? If so, why not add your 3 elements to a single `HBox`? Why create two separate `HBox` objects?

Comment: @BasilBourque the thought was I could have the buttons in one with their own spacing, and the task in another, and then just push them both to either sides. i want both buttons on the right side basically rn to each other

Comment: Show an image of your GUI and a diagram of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SedJ601 I added photos. ik the color scheme awful just idk

Comment: _alot of this is from chatgpt_ I'm certain that those who are commenting or answering did not learn JavaFX from ChatGPT. There are many [good] books on learning JavaFX. Perhaps you should consider investing in [at least] one of them?

Comment: @Abra Do you have any suggestion? im not against investing just I've been doing as much as I can self taught before anything else.

Comment: Are you asking for me to recommend a book? Different books cater to different people. A book that helped me a lot may not help you (and vice versa). Just Google for _JavaFX books_ Alternatively, try this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).

Comment: Be sure to study materials for JavaFX 8 and later. You’ll find much material for earlier versions, but JavaFX evolved dramatically in later versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `Region` as a spacer-filler in a single `HBox`

[Caveat: I am not an expert on JavaFX.]

I asked [a similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77299333/642706), more narrowly focused on a way to accomplish this label-button-button layout with just one `HBox` rather than nesting multiple `HBox` objects.

The [Answer there by makki saud alghamdi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77299349/642706) provides at least part of a possible solution for you. That Answer involves using a [`Region`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) object as a space between the label and the buttons, to fill the void, effectively pushing the buttons to the right.

The key lines of code are:

```java
// Mind the gap between label and buttons.
Region spacer = new Region ( );
HBox.setHgrow ( spacer , Priority.ALWAYS );

HBox rowBox = new HBox ( label , spacer , editButton , completedButton );
```

Here is an entire example app.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloApplication  extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws IOException
    {
        record Event( String title , LocalDate when ) { }
        ObservableList < Event > events =
                FXCollections.observableList (
                        List.of (
                                new Event ( "A bit of text" , LocalDate.now ( ) ) ,
                                new Event ( "Even more text than that." , LocalDate.now ( ).plusDays ( 1 ) ) ,
                                new Event ( "Lots and lots and lots of text for a very long line." , LocalDate.now ( ).plusDays ( 2 ) )
                        )
                );
        ListView < Event > eventView = new ListView <> ( events );
        eventView.setCellFactory ( ( ListView < Event > listView ) -> new ListCell < Event > ( )
        {
            Button editButton = new Button ( "Edit" );
            Button completedButton = new Button ( "Completed" );
            Label label = new Label (  );
            Label labelTwo = new Label( );
            Region spacer = new Region ( );
            VBox vBox = new VBox(label, labelTwo);
            HBox rowBox = new HBox ( vBox , spacer , editButton , completedButton );            
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd");
            {
                // Mind the gap between label and buttons.
                HBox.setHgrow ( spacer , Priority.ALWAYS );
                rowBox.setAlignment ( Pos.CENTER );
                rowBox.setSpacing ( 7 );
            }
                   
            
            @Override
            protected void updateItem ( Event item , boolean empty )
            {
                super.updateItem ( item , empty );
                if ( empty || item == null )
                {
                    setText ( null );
                    setGraphic ( null );
                } 
                else
                {                   
                    label.setText(item.title());
                    labelTwo.setText("\tDue: " + item.when().format(dateTimeFormatter));
                    editButton.setOnAction ( actionEvent ->
                    {                        
                        System.out.println ( "DEBUG - Edit the Event: " + item.title() );
                    });
                    completedButton.setOnAction ( actionEvent ->
                    {
                        System.out.println ( "DEBUG - Completed the Event: " + item.title());
                    });
                    
                    setGraphic ( rowBox );
                }
            }
        } );

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane ( );
        pane.setCenter ( eventView );

        Scene scene = new Scene ( pane , 700 , 300 );
        stage.setScene ( scene );
        stage.setTitle ( "Schedule Example" );
        stage.show ( );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch ( );
    }
}
```

And a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of example app with a ListView showing buttons pushed to the right]

I might not consider this solution complete. If the user narrows the width of the window, the buttons disappear off the right edge of the window. Ideally the buttons would always stay visible within the window, and the too-long label would truncate. I do not know the solution to that issue.

### Binding domain object to your action buttons

> also eventually I will need to figure out how to send the element the button is aligned with into the function for when the button is pressed if anyone has tips for that

Binding each domain object to your buttons is an orthogonal issue from layout of widgets. So you should compose a separate Question on that specific issue.

But briefly…

Notice that your [cell factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setCellFactory(javafx.util.Callback)) is handed a reference to the item, an object of your `Event` class, which is to be displayed by the [`ListView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html). In this line:

```
protected void updateItem ( Event item , boolean empty ) …
```

… that first parameter `Event item` is the key. Notice how I used that reference in my call to `item.toString` while instantiating each `Label`.

```
Label label = new Label ( item.toString ( ) );
```

We can add similar calls in your button action handlers as well.

```java
Button editButton = new Button ( "Edit" );
Button completedButton = new Button ( "Completed" );
editButton.setOnAction ( ( ActionEvent actionEvent ) ->
{
    System.out.println ( "DEBUG - Edit the Event: " + item.toString ( ) );
} );
completedButton.setOnAction ( ( ActionEvent actionEvent ) ->
{
    System.out.println ( "DEBUG - Completed the Event: " + item.toString ( ) );
} );
```

---

By the way, especially while learning, and often more generally, you may find it handy to expand the parameter types in your lambdas. Doing so helps keep it straight in you head as to exactly what objects are in play at every point.

So this:

```
editButton.setOnAction ( ( ActionEvent actionEvent ) -> …
```

… instead of this:

```
editButton.setOnAction ( actionEvent -> …
```

Comment: this is a good answer. The only issue is that you should try to avoid creating Nodes in `updateItem`. Only update the nodes properties or handlers in `updateItem`.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255774/javafx-how-to-dynamically-add-textfields-and-buttons-on-user-input/57256420#57256420

Comment: @Basil That worked perfect thank you, Buttons look great now. The passing of the value however didnt but I found another way.